# File manager with search functionality for Lubuntu or Xubuntu

Tags: unity, xubuntu, lubuntu, files, search

I used Ubuntu 11.10 for some time but since they recommend updates and security, I have to use latest Ubuntu. Unfortunately Ubuntu 14 does not work with my graphics because of heavy 3d since only have a on-board graphics business PC and so they have recommended I try Lubuntu or Xubuntu because of the unity 2d removal. The problem with Xubuntu is it's file manager doesn't have a search functionality to find files in my hard disk and Lubuntu also has same problem but it iss worse because it doesn't even have a program searcher like windows 7 start menu that is available in Xubuntu. So can anyone recommend a file manager with search functionality for Xubuntu or Lubuntu. But with Lubuntu I also need program search too. Thanks for anyone willing to help

Comment: FYI Xubuntu does come with a useful search tool called catfish (I don't know about Lubuntu); its not integrated into your file manager though.

Comment: Lubuntu also comes with a search tool.  Look under PCManFM->Tools->Find Files.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Nemo file manager](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/nemo) under Xubuntu.

Just set it as the default file manager, but *don't delete* the default Xubuntu File Manager.  Just have it as an additional (and default) file manager.

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend **SpaceFM**. It is lightweight and has a search function.
(sudo apt-get install spacefm) 
You can use it as an alternative manager both in Xubuntu or Lubuntu.

As for the search program for Lubuntu try **Gnome-Do**.
(sudo apt-get install gnome-do)

Answer (score 0):

XFE has root window and search capability. You can find it in the software center or Synaptic or simply type sudo apt-get install xfe.